# show a template image if query doesn't exist?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a query that pulls a list of user favourites and displays the images on the page. What i want to be able to do is if there is no favourites to be displayed to display a template image from a file directory.

I am trying to do it like this but it brings up this error:

```
Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PTB1/includes/mod_favourites/favourites.php on line 28

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PTB1/includes/mod_favourites/favourites.php on line 33
```

My codes below can someone please help me and show me how i can do what i am trying to do?

Thanks.

```
<?php
$favorites_set_more = get_user_favorites_more();

if (!file_exists($favorites_set_more)) {
    $favorites_set_more = "data/photos/0/_default.jpg";
}


        while ($favorites2 = mysql_fetch_array($favorites_set_more)) {

echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id={$favorites2['favorite_id']}\"><img width=\"90px\" height=\"90px\" class=\"favorites_pic2\" src=\"data/photos/{$favorites2['favorite_id']}/_default.jpg\" /></a>";
?>


<? } ?>
```

here's the favourites_set_more function:

```
function get_user_favorites_more() {
            global $connection;
            global $_SESSION;
            $query = "SELECT f.favorite_id, p.display_name
                        FROM ptb_favorites f, ptb_profiles p
                        WHERE f.user_id =".$_SESSION['user_id']."
                        AND p.user_id = f.user_id
                        LIMIT 4,12";
                        $favorites_set_more = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($favorites_set_more);
            return $favorites_set_more;
        }
```

Comment: it's hard to advise when we don't see what `get_user_favorites_more()` function does or even returns...

Comment: @Tommy Lincoln: I have updated my answer to give an answer to your updated question.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the error message it says that `file_exists()` is expecting a `string` but you are providing a `resource`. So you should have a look at what `get_user_favorites_more()` is returning. Clearly it is not a `string`.

Make sure your `get_user_favorites_more()` function is returning an non-existing link to an image if no favorite is set so that the `file_exists` function will return false and your default image will be shown.

When you look at your `get_user_favorites_more()` function you are returning the result of `mysql_query($query, $connection)`. This is a `resource` and not a `string`. So you cannot do a `file_exists($favorites_set_more)`. You can change it to something like:

```
<?php
   //Get the favorites for the user
   $favorites_set_more = get_user_favorites_more();

   if (mysql_num_rows($favorites_set_more) == 0) {
      echo "<img width=\"90px\" height=\"90px\" class=\"favorites_pic2\" src=\"data/photos/0/_default.jpg\" />";
   }
   else {
      while ($favoriteImg = mysql_fetch_assoc($favorites_set_more)) {
         echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id=" . $favoriteImg['favorite_id'] . "\">";
         echo "<img width=\"90px\" height=\"90px\" class=\"favorites_pic2\" src=\"data/photos/" . $favoriteImg['favorite_id'] . "/_default.jpg\" />";
         echo "</a>";
      }
   }
?>
```